# Continuous path in square-summable space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots,)$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots)$ $\in \ell_2$.

We define $a(t):[0,2] \to \ell_2 $ as

$a(t) := (y_1,\ldots, y_{n - 1}, x_n + (y_n - x_n)*(t - \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{2^k})*2^n,x_{n + 1},\ldots)$

if $t \in [\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{2^k}$ or $0$ if $n = 1, \sum_{k = 1}^n  \frac{1}{2^k}], n \in \mathbb{N}.$

$a(2) := y$

Is $a$ is a continuous path?

Comment: Are you looking for a continuous path from $x$ to $y$? If so, what is happening with $n$ in relation to $a(t)$?

Comment: Yes. $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I think you mean $\dfrac{1}{2^k}$ everywhere you have written $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ in the summations. But it looks like you are choosing some arbitrary $n$ and changing only the $n$th coordinate. Do you also want to change the $n+1$ and later coordinates in a fashion such as you are changing the $n$th coordinate?

Comment: At any given $t$ I change only one coordinate.

After her change I change the next, etc.

Comment: As written, the answer is no, it is not continuous. Only the $n$th coordinate is changing and $a(t)$ appears to be defined only on the interval $[0,1]$ and consists of horizontal line segments on the intervals $[0,\frac{1}{2}],[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$ etc.

Comment: Perhaps your sequence would be clearer if you wrote a formula for the general term, perhaps call it $z_n$ showing how it depends upon $x, y, n$ and $t$. As it is currently written it is not clear exactly what $a(t)$ is.

Comment: Sorry, i mean $k$ if i wrote $n$ in the summation.

Comment: I think you are trying to define $a(t)$ in such a way as follows: You want an increasing sequence $t_1,t_2,\cdots$ in $[0,2]$ such that for $t_n\le t<t_{n+1}$, $x_n$ has "already arrived" at $y_n$ while $x_{n+1}$ is in the process of moving towards $y_{n+1}$ and the remainder of the sequence $x_{n+2},x_{n+3},\cdots$ are still unchanged. Does this sound accurate?

Answer (score 0):

I am having difficulty understanding your definition of $a(t)$ but I think you are looking for something like the following which I believe is a continuous path from $x=x_1,x_2,\cdots$ to $y=y_1,y_2,\cdots$ in $\ell^2$.

Define the intervals $s_n$ as follows:

For $n\ge0$, $s_n=\left[\dfrac{2^n-1}{2^n},\dfrac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$

For $t\in s_n$, $a(t)=y_1,\cdots,y_{n-1},2^{n+1}\left[\left(t-\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right)y_n+\left(\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^{n+1}}-t \right)x_n\right],x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\cdots$

$a(1)=y$

I believe that this defines a continuous path from $x$ to $y$ in $\ell^2$ on the interval $[0,1]$ but perhaps it does not have particular additional properties which you perhaps wanted the path to have.

Comment: I edited my original answer to correct the formula for the $n$th term. With the correction the $n$th term equals $x_n$ at the left endpoint of the $n+1$st interval and approaches $y_n$ at the right point of the interval. It now looks very close to what was posted in the question.